# TestNG : Unable to use parameter TearUp method in TestBase class

Tags: testng

I am facing the same issue still after updating to 6.9.10.

My case is little different I am using Parameter in BaseTest class

Example:

When I am running test in eclipse by right click "Test1.java" > Run As > TestNG Test

```
Getting error: "Parameter 'username' is required by @Configuration on method beforeClass but has not been marked @Optional or defined"

testNG xml file:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<suite name = "MiscSuite">
    <parameter name="username" value="username">
    <test name = "MiscTest">
        <classes >
            <class name="drkthng.misc.RunAllTestClasses01" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>

TestBase class with a @BeforeClass method: 


public abstract class TestBase {
    @Parameters({"username"})
    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass(String username) {
        System.out.println(username);
    }
}


public class Test1 extends TestBase {

    @BeforeClass
    public void startUp() {
        Assert.assertTrue(false);
    }

    @Test
    public void Test01() {
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This error you are getting is because you have used @Parameter annotation for your `beforeClass` method of TestBase class and no parameter will be passed to this method when you run this class by right click > Run As > TestNG Test. This can be resolved by passing optional parameter in your `beforeClass` method. Modify your `beforeClass` method as

```
    @Parameters({"username"})
    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass(@Optional("username") String username) {
        System.out.println(username);
    }
```

@Optional annotation passes the value you have specified when you run java class without testng.xml. Hope it helps!.

Comment: Or he can configure the parameter in the eclipse plugin too.